# Python. Code fails to work with larger numbers, but works with smaller numbers. Why?

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to write a function that adds two numbers together and returns their sum in binary. The binary number returned should be a string. The code seems to work with smaller numbers, but fails with very large numbers.

Edit:

The correct answer needs to be (for this given test):
1100011000111000101111110010101100001001000111000000001000001100111000

My code outputs:
1100011000111000101111110010101100001001000111000000000000000000000000

```
def add_binary(a,b):
    c = a + b
    remainder_list = []
    remainder = 0
    while c >= 2 and isinstance(c,int) == True:
        remainder = c % 2
        remainder = str(remainder)
        remainder_list += remainder
        c = c/2
        c = int(c)
    else:
        remainder = 1
        remainder = str(remainder)
        remainder_list+=remainder
    remainder_list =  [ele for ele in reversed(remainder_list)]
    remainder_list = ''.join(remainder_list)
    return remainder_list


print(add_binary(800998058044843321128,113138032179979557904))
```

Comment: What is the error? I tried your code on my machine and it runs absolutely fine for very large numbers also.

Comment: Just added a bit more description. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error. You need to use floor division:

```
c = c // 2
```

This will fix it. The original `c = c/2` turns your `c` into `float` which fails for large numbers. Compare:

```
>>> int(914136090224822879032 / 2)
457068045112411422720
>>> 914136090224822879032 // 2
457068045112411439516
```

With that change, you will get:

```
>>> add_binary(800998058044843321128,113138032179979557904)
'1100011000111000101111110010101100001001000111000000001000001100111000'
```

if you want a short version:

```
def add_binary(a, b):
    return '{:b}'.format(a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

That's because when you use `/` it will turn the result to float. A float cannot cover so many bits so it will turn out to be `2.285340225562057e+20` at the first step. Losing some digits after you use `int`.

`int(c)`: 457068045112411422720

`c // 2`: 457068045112411439516

If we use `//` instead, it will still save those digits.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you want to do convert the numbers in binaries yourself. But an other way to do the same thing with a bit simpler solution would be to it like this:

```
>>> def add_binarys(a,b):
...     return str(bin(a+b))
... 
>>> add_binarys(2,4)
'0b110'
>>> add_binarys(800998058044843321128,113138032179979557904)
'0b1100011000111000101111110010101100001001000111000000001000001100111000'
>>>
```

With this way you wouldn't have the problems with long and int.